# SQL query works when run as query on server, but will not work from PHP code

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm running this via PHP and well the first query gets run perfectly then right after it I run the second query and it does nothing. Its rows never get updated for some reason, but when I type out the query manually on the sql server, it works perfectly.

Anyone have any idea why its not working in the php code?

```
$qry = "UPDATE Matches SET winner ='$winner' WHERE TOURN_KEY = '$tournKey'AND MATCH_KEY='$matchKey' ";

$result = @mysql_query($qry);

$qryPoints = "UPDATE members, MemberBets SET members.points = members.points + MemberBets.amountBet + MemberBets.amountBet WHERE members.member_id=MemberBets.member_id and MemberBets.MATCH_KEY ='$matchKey' and MemberBets.TOURN_KEY = '$tournyKey' and MemberBets.player = '$winner'";

$resultPoints = @mysql_query($qryPoints);
```

Comment: Try and print those queries and see if they are what they are supposed to be.

Comment: Could you `echo $qryPoints` at the end and tell us what it looks like?

Comment: Another thing you could do is print out the error mySQL gives you, ie: $resultPoints = mysql_query($qryPoints) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: UPDATE members, MemberBets SET members.points = members.points + MemberBets.amountBet + MemberBets.amountBet WHERE members.member_id=MemberBets.member_id and MemberBets.MATCH_KEY ='53' and MemberBets.TOURN_KEY = '' and MemberBets.player = 'player1'

holy crap what happen to my $tournKEY value hmm... going to echo the working query and see if its blank too then at least now I know what direction to look in thanks

Comment: See @tan 's answer below. You have a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have a typo.  You have a `$tournKey` variable in the first query and a `$tournyKey` variable in the second.  Since you say the first query works, I'm guessing the second variable name is wrong.

Comment: lol i guess this is what i get for trying to code late at night dead tired... I need sleep

Thanks so much man would have never spotted that today